# Reusing components in react and telling the component which key: value of a state to change

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-component

I'm having a little bit of difficulty figuring out how to reuse components in many places.

Obviously the reason why react is so good is because you can create common components and reuse them across many different pages, or just multiple times in the same page.

I have this component for  displaying a dropdown that a user can use to select a new value, and change their settings. This component is reused in many different places on my website.

```js
                  <ChannelSelect
                    channelID={
                      saveEnabled.saveEnabled.newSettings.verificationPanel.channelID
                    }
                    settings={
                      saveEnabled.saveEnabled.newSettings.verificationPanel.channelID
                    }
                  />
```

What I am struggling with is telling this component which `key: value` in the state (object) to change. This is because simply passing in the code below, doesn't actually allow me to change the state of this specific key.

```js
settings={saveEnabled.saveEnabled.newSettings.verificationPanel.channelID}
```

In my select menus `onChange` event I have the code snippet below. However, this doesn't actually allow me to change the specific value declare, it would actually just overwrite the whole object.

```js
 const { saveEnabled, setSaveEnabled } = useContext(SaveContext);
 const onChange = (event) => {
   props.settings = "newValue"
   setSaveEnabled(props.settings)
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: problem with question - you should ask question more clear - I can't realize your question

Comment: also you must write this const {save,setSave} = useState();

Comment: I figured the solution. I have to pass in a function as a prop. 
Also, why do i need to use useState? I am using context due to the state being global across my components